# Why does AndroidStudio tell me that this directory already exists but won't show it in the Project view?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I'd like to create a directory where I can store some XMLs, but AndroidStudio won't show me the directory I've created. What is going on here?

This is Step 3 in [**this tutorial here**](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/android-animation-using-kotlin-ef385b5b5dea).

Comment: Invalidates cache and restart Android Studio -> File -> Invalidates Cache / Restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a Resource Directory named "animation" was the problem, apparently. Creating a directory named "anim", as the tutorial I was following suggested, works.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to Invalidate cache and restart android studio. You will able to see the folder in the res folder.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I invalidated the cache three times, restarting Android Studio each time. I even tried rebooting my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on res folder and click **Show in Explorer**. Then if the *animation* folder exists delete it and then try again.
Folder name should be `anim`. Android Studio will not recognize any invalid name.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I deleted the `animation` directory and recreated it using the same New Resource Directory dialog, but the issue persists. The directory is created, but is not visible in Android Studio.

Comment: Android Studio will not recognize any invalid resource name. The folder should be anim or animator